# How to convert my Native PHP Code to Codeigniter code

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I want to convert my native php code about graphical statistic, the chart is filled with total amount of student per class, im using chart.js for my statistic , please help me to convert my code to the CodeIgniter code guys, Thanks.

i'ver been try to put all folder and code to controller, but nothing show. and i dont know how to convert it to CI.

this is my koneksi.php code :

```
<?php
    $koneksi = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","grafik_mahasiswa");
?>
```

And this is my index.php code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test and Try</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="chartjs/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
        font-family: roboto;
    }

    table{
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    </style>


    <center>
        <h2>Try me</h2>
    </center>


    <?php 
    include 'koneksi.php';
    ?>

    <div style="width: 800px;margin: 0px auto;">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Nama Mahasiswa</th>
                <th>NIM</th>
                <th>Fakultas</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php 
            $no = 1;
            $data = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mahasiswa");
            while($d=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $d['nama']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $d['nim']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $d['fakultas']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php 
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Teknik", "Fisip", "Ekonomi", "Pertanian"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '',
                    data: [
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_teknik = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mahasiswa where fakultas='teknik'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_teknik);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_ekonomi = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mahasiswa where fakultas='ekonomi'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_ekonomi);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_fisip = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mahasiswa where fakultas='fisip'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_fisip);
                    ?>, 
                    <?php 
                    $jumlah_pertanian = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from mahasiswa where fakultas='pertanian'");
                    echo mysqli_num_rows($jumlah_pertanian);
                    ?>
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero:true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a read at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/connecting.html, this might help you you getting started with CI. Good luck!

If you have other questions, try to be as specific as possible, as this makes it easier to answer. How to convert native PHP to CI is quite broad for example, and not easy to answer in a few lines.

Comment: Hey thanks, and sorry if its not as specific as you want :)

Comment: No worries! Being more specific might help you get rid of the downvotes and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

when u have installed codeigniter go on config-> database.php and change the existing code to get this :

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'grafik_mahasiswa';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Create a model with all ur sql and a controller to make link between ur model and ur view.

This will help you :

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: Hi! If you want to thank Martin, you can consider voting his answer up :)